# Fitting normalized data to discrete distribution

Tags: normalization, discrete-data

I have a graph which represents a P(x) vs. x data where x can have 10 possible discrete outcomes.

Data looks as follows: {{200, 0.0058668}, {306, 0.0503333}, {411, 0.163055}, {520, 0.203411}, {624, 0.175508}, {732, 0.131158}, {840, 0.0892774}, {950, 0.0613757}, {1055, 0.0416968}, {1160, 0.0277754}, {1268, 0.0228999}, {1378, 0.01898004}},

[image]

where 200, 306, 411... are the outcomes and alongside I have the probabilities of occurrences. You can see that all P(x)'s sum up to 1, making the data normalized.

Now if I want to fit, suppose, a Negative Binomial distribution through it, how exactly do I do it? I am confused because of the normalization. The curve which passes through all the points will have its area under the curve much greater than 1, as the discrete probabilities alone sum up to 1. So how come a normalized negative binomial distribution can represent this data? Do I have to add some multiplicative area factor to the distribution? but then also it becomes vague to fit a un-normalized distribution to a normalized data...

Comment: The negative binomial distribution defines a discrete random variable, so there's no curve or area under it; but it can take any non-negative integer value. Your data is clearly not sampled from a negative binomial distribution, & it's safe to say there's no brand-name distribution concentrating probability mass on 200, 306, 411 &c. Perhaps the data could be meaningfully re-expressed - a count of batches or something. Take a step back & explain where they came from & what you want to learn from them.

Comment: @Scortchi is on target here. How these data arise is the main area to clarify. These seem more like measurements that as a result of a quirky convention are reported as a series of discrete values. (Puzzlingly, the gaps vary between 104 and 110.) If so, something like a gamma or lognormal might be more appropriate.

Comment: You are very much right. I also could not interpret the fact of this "concentrating probability mass". The data actually came from some experiment and now, after reading your comment, I think that they have summed up all the probabilities of a certain bin, and assigned them to a particular mid-value of the bin, may be. And then this is not a histogram. Then as far as I understand I have to get the histograms at first to fit them to some distribution. Am I right?

Comment: @Nick Cox, about fitting this to Gamma or Lognormal, assuming that the experimental data has some convention underlying, I hope it does not matter to use a Normalized distribution or not? As you can see, it cant be fitted by normalized distribution, I have to add some area factor.

Comment: You remain unclear on what the data are and how they were produced, making it difficult to advise you well. In my favourite software (Stata) I can fit gamma and lognormal distributions directly to data in the form you have, just using the observed probabilities as weights; there is no need for a mystic "area factor". Also, you appear to mean by "normalized distribution" that the probabilities sum to 1; nothing special about that, as it should always be true. The value in the highest bin is slightly puzzling: can you rule its including all the highest values?

Comment: Sorry - "Concentrating probability mass at x" just means putting lumps of probability at that particular value of x. Knowing rather than guessing how the data were generated would be better - ask whoever you got it from. Fitting a distribution from a histogram can be done knowing the bin frequencies (not just probabilities) & cut-offs, but is less accurate than fitting to the raw data.

Comment: @Nick Cox, the data comes from some single cell measurements. It will be really helpful if you clarify some of your statements, like "using the observed probabilities as weights". And when you are fitting the data with some Gamma/lognormal, are you getting the area under the fitted curve as 1? That is what I meant by normalized distribution. Because when I am fitting, the area under the fitted curve becomes much greater than 1. So I cant understand physically what is meant by fitting some un-normalized distribution to a normalized data.

Comment: You know approximately the sample mean & variance from your data. You also know the theoretical mean & variance of a negative binomial distribution (or log-normal or whatever) in terms of its parameters. So equate one to the other & solve for the parameters. Not great, but probably the best you can do without more information. The fitted distribution will be normalized, by definition. Don't know why your fitting method doesn't give a normalized probability distribution because you haven't said what it is.

Comment: You just have observed values and their relative frequencies. Any program that fits a probability distribution fits a function that  automatically sums or integrates to 1 over the support. You needn't try to invent a fitting method, just to identify appropriate software. I agree with @Scortchi's advice, not least that the raw data are much preferable to binned data.

Comment: I was using Origin to fit the Lognormal. It always associates an offset and an area/amplitude parameter with the default parameters (mu,sigma)of the lognormal. The form looks like y0+A*LogNormal[mu,sigma]. And after fitting the area under fitted curve comes of the order of a

Comment: I was using Origin to fit the Lognormal. It always associates an offset and an area/amplitude parameter with the default parameters (mu,sigma)of the lognormal. The form looks like y0+A*LogNormal[mu,sigma]. And after fitting the area under fitted curve comes of the order of A. This is area factor I mentioned earlier. The x-range is almost upto 1500, how can a normalized curve go from 0 to 1500 and have a height of 0.1~0.2? I think some scaling problem underlies here which I am not understanding.

Comment: I have never used Origin. You now have a software question best taken up with Origin people. Personally I would prefer using maximum likelihood to fit these distributions; curve fitting is here too ad hoc to my taste.

Comment: Yeah, let me figure out what the actual problem is. The main thing I am concerned about is how can a normalized curve go from 0 to 1500 and have a height of 0.1~0.2? The area under it must exceed 1.
Anyways, thanks for your comments @Nick Cox and Scortchi